# Como estilizar os textos que o iframe puxa?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Estou usando esse código pra pegar resultados das loterias, mais especificamente da Mega Sena, e preciso estilizar o texto que o iframe traz. O resultado que o iframe puxa é como se fosse XML, não tenho certeza, mas preciso tirar os caracteres que estão aparecendo junto com o texto e deixar só o texto, depois preciso estilizar tipo centralizar, colocar cor no texto, mudar posição, como se fosse diagramar, já tentei com CSS, mas não funcionou os estilos no texto, apenas no fundo do texto. Se puderem me ajudar, desde já agradeço.

Esse é o meu código HTML que uso:

```html
<iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" src="http://api.onemidia.tv.br/igor.php" 
        frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0"
        style="font-family: verdana;width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

E esse é o meu código CSS que uso:

```css
iframe{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 color: red;
 font-family: arial;
 background: #74E8B8;
}
```

Comment: o iframe é um "elemento" embebedado da na página, é um conteúdo externo que vc busca e renderiza dentro do seu documento, e infelizmente não tem nada que vc possa fazer para muda-lo, seja cor de fonte, ícone ou imagem, até mesmo por uma questão de segurança e direitos.

Comment: Entendi, mas com PHP da?

Comment: Se a fonte do iframe for do mesmo domínio vc consegue mudar.

Comment: @Sam como posso mudar?

Comment: Só consegue com JavaScript. Dá uma pesquisada que vc vai achar inúmeros exemplos.

Comment: Ok, agradeço a ajuda.